# Application crashed when "restoring backup" request sent to server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm developing a client server project in c#. One of the tasks, I implemented was to backup and restore backup files. But in restoring the backup file, when I started the recovery operation from inside the software, the software crashed and the database remained in restoring...

[image]

Also, the my services were suspended in server.

I did not find the desired result in my searches. But one solution that came to my mind was to block all queries from the client and services to the database until the restore operation was complete.

But this also takes a little time because the number of queries is almost too much.

Now what better solution to do this?

Restore code implemented in my service:

```
public void StartRestoreDatabase(string backupFilePath, string toDatabaseName = null)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name.IsNullOrEmpty()) { Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "SQL Restore"; }
        if (toDatabaseName.IsNullOrEmpty()) toDatabaseName = this.Database;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.MasterConnectionString))
        {
            using (TExclusiveAccessToDatabase Locker = new TExclusiveAccessToDatabase(con, this.Database))
            {
                //The FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors property and InfoMessage event ensure that the C# code captures these messages during execution rather than only at the end.
                con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
                con.InfoMessage += OnInfoMessage;
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
                //The stats = 1 clause tells SQL Server to emit severity 0 messages at the specified percentage interval (in this case 1%).
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("RESTORE DATABASE @toDatabaseName FROM DISK = @backupFilePath WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, stats = 1", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toDatabaseName", toDatabaseName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@backupFilePath", backupFilePath);

                    cmd.CommandTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                con.InfoMessage -= OnInfoMessage;
                con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = false;
            }
        }
    }).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.Exception != null)
        {
            OnCompleted(task.Exception);
        }
        else if (!_Exception.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            OnCompleted(new Exception(_Exception));
        }
        else
        {
            OnCompleted(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You could use SINGLEUSER MODE

Comment: "the software crashed"  Well, you need to fix that.  Why did it crash?

Comment: Because when restoring the SQL Server backup, it deletes all the tables and restores them all from the backup file. And when this happens, the software because it is querying the required tables and the tables are not available until the end of the recovery time, the software crashes.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you have two databases, and you are trying to refresh database 2 by restoring database 1 over the top of it, but there are active users in database 2 when you try to do this. Is that right? Is database 2 a reporting database or something?

Comment: No, I only have one.